# adjust parameters of genetic algorithm

Tags: neural-network, genetic-algorithm

My project is to do an AI playing [2048](https://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) in python using genetic algorithm and neural-networks. 
I'm using neural-network as the structure to compute what is the best move giving the current grid and the genetic algorithm to adjust the weights and bias. So I'm not using back-propagation.

For now, the best scores are only 512 which is just above what a fully random game product (in average a random run reach 128 and most lucky gives 256).

In a lot of tutorial in artificial intelligence, they said that find the right adjustments is a matter of experience. Since that's my first project in this domain I have no such experience. 
**My question is**, giving all the information below, **what can be adjusted to improve the results**? 
Bold numbers are parameters that I think must have to be adjusted.

I'm following the main steps in genetics algorithm:

1. generation:

   I'm generating a population of **600** networks. 
   The structure of the networks is:

   - **16** neurons for input layer (one for each square of the grid)
   - **3** hidden layers with **10** neurons each
   - **4** neurons for output
2. evaluation

   I test all the population by having them do a full game of 2048 (of course it's a non-graphical simulation) and collecting their score and the value of the max tile. (I use multiprocessing to do several runs in parallel)
   I calculate the fitness by **score+(maxTileValue)²**
3. selection

   I simply sort them and kill the **half** most bad fitness
4. reproduction

   for every network I need to recreate, I pick one of the survivors and I add to each weight a random value between **-0.5 and 0.5 times 100/(average fitness of generation)**

I'm repeating that for **200** generations.

I'm not using Tensorflow or any library.
Complete code on github(https://github.com/Nonoreve/2048Solver/tree/master/solver/AIsolver)

*(I'm a French student so apologies for syntax and grammar)*.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I think a better way of reproducing is merging the half best networks. one way doing so is: randomly choose 600 pairs and average between their weights, or maybe use average, weighted by net's score.

Comment: Consider normalizing the input layer to a constant range, like 0-1.

Comment: Also, it may be helpful using RNN or CNN, but since you are not using tensorflow it is much harder. Of course, you don't forget applying Relu on the hidden layers. And Just a guess, try using a decreasing number of neurons, for example `[14, 10, 8]`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'll try the pairs system (before I was using the average off the whole survivors and it was terrible) Normalizing the inputs is a great idea. For now I'm using sigmoid, you think that Relu will give better results ?

Comment: Relu is better for the backpropagation so it's more common, but it also more easy to implement☺.

Comment: I applied your reproduction system and the normalization on the inputs (others changes need a deep modification off the code structure) and I get interesting results: He's still stuck to 512 but he evolve naturally to put bigger tiles on the upper left corner.

Comment: Ok. I think the best thing you can do now is implementing CNN, how hard it can be for you? If it's too much, maybe you can something like RNN.

Comment: Another minor optimization is to calculate the final score like: `game_score + Max*log2(Max)`

Comment: I don't know how to use RNNs and I think I should use a library for this level of complexity.

Comment: Anyway it seems that I reach the limits of genetic algorithm and if I want to go further, I have to rework my code from the beginning. I will still test the minor optimization.